# What's the difference in mono/stereo audio recording on android device

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

I know stereo means the signals from multiple channels. But can anyone tell me what does it mean by setting audioformat to "stereo" when use audiotrack class to record audio data? Does it mean the recorded raw data consists of the data from two different microphones?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Does it mean the recorded raw data consists of the data from two different microphones?

If the device only has one microphone, both channels are identical.

But if there are two or more microphones it depends on the firmware of the manufacturer: He decides if still only the output of one microphone is sent to both channels (and the other microphone(s) are used e.g. for noise suppression), or if the two channels of the recorded data indeed contain the signals of two different microphones.